# add an error message to panel in apache wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have an apache wicket panel for google recaptcha where I integrate wicket with google recaptcha and everything is working as it should, but I need to add an error message or feedbackpanel I am not quite good with wicket, so please advise me what is the best solution for my case?

```
public class ReCaptchaPanel extends Panel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8346261172610929107L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReCaptchaPanel.class);

    final String publicKey = "6LdrIgceAAAAADWF-gIz_OHJg_5gLu7IVw11hTnt";
    final String secretKey = "6LdrIgceAAAAAE9qxHViBj3Sl8uyqUVdluugPRTq";
    final String scriptClassName = "data-sitekey";
    final String recCaptchaClassName = "g-recaptcha";
    String currentLanguage = getLocale().getLanguage();
String scriptValue = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=" + currentLanguage;

/* in the following link you can find the language codes
 * https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language
 * */


public ReCaptchaPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    final IFeedbackMessageFilter feedbackFilter = new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this);
    final FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback", feedbackFilter);
    feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(feedbackPanel);
    add(new Label("reCaptchaComponent", "").add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("class", recCaptchaClassName))
            .add(new SimpleAttributeModifier(scriptClassName, publicKey)));
    add(new Label("reCaptchaScript", "").add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("src", scriptValue)));

}


public ReCaptchaPanel(String id, IModel model) {
    super(id, model);
}


/**
 * Validates Google reCAPTCHA V2 .
 *
 * @param secretKey Secret key (key given for communication between arena and Google)
 * @param response  reCAPTCHA response from client side (g-recaptcha-response).
 * @return true if validation successful, false otherwise.
 */

public synchronized boolean isCaptchaValid(String secretKey, String response) {
    try {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
                params = "secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + response;

        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream out = http.getOutputStream();
        out.write(params.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        InputStream res = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        res.close();
        log.info("Google ReCaptcha has been verified");
        return json.getBoolean("success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.error(" Google ReCaptcha failed");
    return false;
}

public synchronized boolean isCaptchaValid() {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ApplicationBase.getHttpServletRequest();
    assert httpServletRequest != null;
    String response = httpServletRequest.getParameter("g-recaptcha-

response");
        return isCaptchaValid(secretKey, response);
    }

}
```

I use this panel in another wicket component ( form) ,

```
  class FormEmail extends Form { 
   .........


          final ReCaptchaPanel reCaptchaPanel = new ReCaptchaPanel("reCaptchaPanel") {
            /**
             * @see org.apache.wicket.Component#isVisible()
             */
            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                SessionBase session = (SessionBase) getSession();
                ItemListPanelConfigParams configParams = new ItemListPanelConfigParams(session);
                return configParams.isShowCaptcha();
            }
        };

        add(reCaptchaPanel);

        Button buttonSend = new Button("buttonSend") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                onSendCallback(emailRecipient, emailReplyTo, comment);
                setResponsePage(callbackPage);
            }
        };
```

what i need to achieve is that add a message when the verify method in code above is false; I mean an error message, anyone knows how.

Comment: Who is calling `#isCaptchaValid()` method ? Is it called in a normal or Ajax request ?

Comment: Nothing is calling it yet, that is my question how I can implement a validator to check the button if it is checked or not , and raise a message to the user if he did not check the captcha button @martin-g